# Suppose $[a], [b] \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $[a]\cdot[b] = [0]$. Is it necessarily true that either $[a] = [0]$ or $[b] = [0]$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $R$ be the equivalence relation $\equiv \pmod{n}$. Suppose $[a], [b] \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $[a]\cdot[b] = [0]$. Is it necessarily true that either $[a] = [0]$ or $[b] = [0]$?

**Proof**:

*Premises*:

$
1.\, [a]\cdot[b] = [0]\\
2. \forall x\forall y\forall k(x \equiv y \pmod{n} \to x \equiv ky \pmod{n})
$

*Assume* $[a] \neq [0]$:

$
\begin{align*}
  &\langle\text{Assumption} \rangle\\
  &c \in [b]\\
  \iff&\langle\text{Def. of $[b]$} \rangle\\
  & cRb\\
  \iff&\langle\text{Def. of $R$} \rangle\\
  & c \equiv b \pmod{n}\\
  \iff&\langle\text{By Premise 2} \rangle\\
  & c \equiv ab \pmod{n}\\
  \iff&\langle\text{Def. of $R$} \rangle\\
  & cRab\\
  \iff&\langle\text{Def. of $[ab]$} \rangle\\
  & c \in [ab]\\
  \iff&\langle\text{$[a][b]=[0]$} \rangle\\
  &c \in [0]\\
\end{align*}
$

$[b] \subseteq [0]$

- Is my proof heading in the right direction ?
- Is the addition of Premise 2 correct? How can I prove it to use it in my proof ?

Comment: In $\Bbb{Z}_4$ we have $[2]_4[2]_4=[0]_4$ but $[2]_4 \neq [0]_4$. Also your premise 2 is incorrect. It should be $$x \equiv y \pmod{n} \implies kx \equiv ky \pmod{n}.$$ In fact, for composite $n>1$, we can always find **non-zero** $a,b$ such that $ab \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$.

Comment: Thank you, @Anurag A !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the statement is false as well as the "Premise 2".

But you can try to show this: if $p$ is prime, then $[a]_p[b]_p=[0]_p$ implies $[a]_p=[0]_p$ or $[b]_p=[0]_p$. There is more or less nothing to prove apart from correctly using the definition of congruence.

In particular in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ there are no zero-divisors. On the contrary, you can also show that if $n$ is composite then there exist zero-divisors in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you, @Alessio Del Vigna. What's the meaning of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and what do you mean by "in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ there are no zero-divisors ?

Comment: You're welcome @F.Zer! The notation $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is the same as $\mathbb{Z}_n$, but emphasises the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a quotient ring, in particular it is the quotient ring of $\mathbb{Z}$ modulo the ideal generated by $n$ (which is $n\mathbb{Z}=\{nz\,:\, z\in \mathbb{Z}\}$). 
In general, for a ring $A$, a non-zero element $a$ is a *zero-divisor* if there is a non-zero element $b\in A$ such that $a\cdot b = 0_A$. For instance in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ we have $[2]_6[3]_6=[0]_6$, so that $[2]_6$ and $[3]_6$ are zero-divisors. This cannot happen in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ when $p$ is prime.

Comment: Thank you ! Why do you say that it cannot happen in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, when $p$ is prime ?

Comment: Because, as I stated in my answer, for $p$ prime we can prove that the zero-product property holds, that is a product is zero if and only if at least one of the two factors is zero.